# Advantages and disadvantages of bevel gears

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

What are the advantages and disadvantages of bevel gears?

This is what I've already found:

**Advantages:**

- possibility to change operation angle

**Disadvantages:**

- must be precisely mounted
- shafts' bearings will be exposed to significant forces
- limited gear ratio < 5

Do you know any other? Especially advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advantage :-**
       Differing of the number of teeth (effectively diameter) on each wheel allows mechanical advantage to be changed. By increasing or decreasing the ratio of teeth between the drive and driven wheels one may change the ratio of rotations between the two, meaning that the rotational drive and torque of the second wheel can be changed in relation to the first, with speed increasing and torque decreasing, or speed decreasing and torque increasing.

**Disadvantage :-**
            One wheel of such gear is designed to work with its complementary wheel and no other.

Answer (score 2):

Another advantage is to counter mechanical thrust which is why the bearings are usually conical

Comment: Are you saying that compressive axial load on one shaft is supported but the other gear?

Comment: Some off road vehicles use thrust bearings behind bevel gears in a differential gear arrangement. The thrust from radial inertia is absorbed and transmitted as extra drive but also increased wear.